# How come foo<float>(1.0f) calls a specialization instead of a non-template overload?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

I have just a simple question, check this code please:

```
template < typename A >
void foo( A a )
{ cout<<"1\n"; };

template< >
void foo<float>( float a )
{  cout<<"2\n"; }

void foo( float a )
{ cout<<"3\n"; }


int main()
{
    foo<float>( 1.0f );
}
```

Compiled with g++ 4.7.2 works of course, but what is not clear to me is why the output is "2" instead of "3".

As far as I remember a non template function shall be always preferred towards a template one, so why is called the specialized foo?

Comment: You would need to call `foo(1.0f)` to get the non-template.

Comment: `foo<float>` is the name of a template function specialisation (which you happen to have explicitly specialised; if you hadn't, you would see "1" instead).  If you don't provide the `<...>` syntax, overload resolution will indeed prefer the non-template function.

Comment: See also http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Comment: @jrok: No, since `foo<float>` and `foo` are distinct names.  The fact that writing just `foo` when calling a function *also* causes function templates like `foo<float>` to be looked up is just a "feature" of overload resolution.

Answer (score 9):

You specifically are using the specialized version. Had you done this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T a) {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

void foo(float a) {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
int main(void) {
    foo(1.0f);
}
```

than it would have picked the non templated version.